# Сделать список из словарей

Tags: python, файлы, list, словари, dict

Уже очень долго ломаю голову и начинаю делать всякий бред. Помогите мне грамотно сделать список из словарей.
Задача заключается в файле с текстом:

```
60b90c1c13067a15887e1ae1,Tayson,3
60b90c2413067a15887e1ae2,Vika,1
60b90c2e13067a15887e1ae3,Barsik,2
60b90c3b13067a15887e1ae4,Simon,12
60b90c4613067a15887e1ae5,Tessi,5
```

Мне нужно сделать функцию которая будет возвращать список из словарей из этого файла в виде:

```
[
{"id": "60b90c1c13067a15887e1ae1", "name": "Tayson", "age": "3"},
{"id": "60b90c2413067a15887e1ae2", "name": "Vika", "age": "1"},
{"id": "60b90c2e13067a15887e1ae3", "name": "Barsik", "age": "2"},
{"id": "60b90c3b13067a15887e1ae4", "name": "Simon", "age": "12"},
{"id": "60b90c4613067a15887e1ae5", "name": "Tessi", "age": "5"},
]
```

Но я не могу додуматься как сделать список из словарей который будет содержать каждую строку отдельно.
Мой код:

```
from pathlib import Path



def get_cats_info(path):
    cats = {'id': None,
            'name': None,
            'age': None
           }
    cats_list = []
    file_with_cats = open(path, 'r')
    cats_rows = file_with_cats.readlines()
    for cat in cats_rows:
        cat = cat.split(',')
        print(cat)
        cats['id'] = cats.get('id')
        cats['name'] = cat[1]
        cats['age'] = cat[2]
        cats_list.append(cats)


file_with_cats.close()


path_to_file_with_cats = Path('C:\Projects\Test_Project\Cats_list.txt')

get_cats_info(path_to_file_with_cats)
```

После строки cat = cat.split(',') все пошло по одному месту. Если вывести эту строку - это будет то из чего должен состоять каждый словарь в списке. Нужно сделать цикл с ним, если это возможно вообще.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы почти всё сделали. На каждом шаге нужен новый словарь

```
def get_cats_info(path):
    cats_list = []
    file_with_cats = open(path, 'r')
    cats_rows = file_with_cats.readlines()
    for cat in cats_rows:
        cat = cat.split(',')
        cats = {}
        cats['id'] = cat[0]
        cats['name'] = cat[1]
        cats['age'] = cat[2]
        cats_list.append(cats)
    file_with_cats.close()
    return cats_list
```

Comment: Супер, спасибо. А там еще age в конце выводит '\n' как это убрать? Нужно учитывать что в самой последней строке этого символа нет. Поэтому мой вариант cats['age'] = cat[2][:-1] не работает

Comment: Сделал при помощи метода строки replace('\n',  '')

Answer (score 1):

```
path = 'file.txt'
arr = []
try:
    with open(path) as file:
        while (text := file.readline()):
            text = text.split(',')
            arr.append({'id': text[0], 'name': text[1], 'age': text[2]})
except IOError as ex:
    print(ex)
print(arr)
```